# SQL - Procedure & Query with SUM & return

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'am trying to do a **Procedure** with a sub query who do a **SUM**.
The procedure should list all items of `<ProductFinished>` (I.e Pizza etc) and list the ingredients , with unit price of ingredient and the total sum of cost of the finished product.

UML of the Database : 
[image]

```
The product <NameFInishedProduct> is composed of 
        3 <NameRawProduct> priced <BuyPrice> € each
        1 <NameRawProduct> priced <BuyPrice> € each
The total price of the <NameFInishedProduct> is <SUM> €.
```

Witch in normal output should look like

```
The product Pizza is composed of
        3 Tomato priced 2 € each
        1 Cheese priced 1€ each
The total price of the Pizza is 7 €.
```

Comment: This is not a jobs board. We are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What have you tried? What are your problems? PS @Marc > I completely agree with you.\

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT textLine FROM
(
    SELECT  pf.NameFinishedProduct As Name, 
            1 as Typ, 
            N'The product '+pf.NameFInishedProduct+N' is composed of' As textLine
    FROM    ProductFinished As pf
 UNION ALL
    SELECT  pf.NameFinishedProduct, 
            2, 
            N'        '+CAST(co.QuantityUsed As NVARCHAR(80))+N' '+pr.NameRawProduct+N' priced '+CAST(pr.BuyPrice As NVARCHAR(80))+N' € each'
    FROM    ProductFinished As pf
    JOIN    Composition     As co ON co.IdProductFinished = pf.IdProductFinished
    JOIN    ProductRaw      As pr ON pr.IdProductRaw      = pr.IdProductRaw
 UNION ALL
    SELECT  pf.NameFinishedProduct, 
            3, 
            N'The total price of the '+pf.NameFInishedProduct+N' is '+CAST(SUM(co.QuantityUsed * pr.BuyPrice) AS NVARCHAR(80))+N' €.'
    FROM    ProductFinished As pf
    JOIN    Composition     As co ON co.IdProductFinished = pf.IdProductFinished
    JOIN    ProductRaw      As pr ON pr.IdProductRaw      = pr.IdProductRaw
    GROUP BY pf.NameFinishedProduct
) AS A
ORDER BY Name, Typ
```

Of course I have nothing to test it on, so caveat emptor.

Comment: I wrote a up the main query and thought about posting. OP is supposed to write a "procedure" and a "subquery" in some form. Clearly OP can't turn in your solution as is for the homework assignment but hopefully you've provided enough for him to tear apart and actually learn something in the process.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yah, I know.  The Procedure is easy. Writing it as a single big procedure like I did is "hard".  But I was bored, and yeah, figured they could learn something.